How to create multiple javascripts have the same notification
Here are two JavaScripts. There is also a notification script.
I want to combine two javascripts in one and have both javascripts show the same notification.
This is the two different javascripts with the same notification.
<script>
function copy(that){
  var text = that.textContent;
  var input = document.getElementById('cb');
  input.value = input.value + text +'\n';
  var inp =document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(inp)
inp.value =that.textContent
inp.select();
    document.execCommand('copy',false);

var notification = document.getElementById('symc');
    notification.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(() => {
        notification.style.display = 'none';
     }, 1000);
}
</script>

<script>
function co() {
  var input = document.getElementById("cb");
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(input.value);

var notification = document.getElementById('symc');
    notification.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(() => {
        notification.style.display = 'none';
     }, 1000);
}
</script>

<span id="symc">Copied</span>

<div id="ca">
<input id="cb">
<button onclick="co()">Copy</button>
</div>

This is the notification script
var notification = document.getElementById('symc');
    notification.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(() => {
        notification.style.display = 'none';
     }, 1000);

Please help me how can I mix two script in one js area...
<script>

</script>

Thanks.

Remove the </script> <script> that's between the two scripts.  Then it's one script.  Not sure what I'm missing that you're asking?  Despite the lack of indenting, there are two separate var notiification which only apply inside each function (so a case of DRY) - make this its own function function notify(msg) {... and call it from each

You also might want to look at the clipboard API instead of the deprecated execCommand

Pedantic point: indentation is for readability, and conveys intention/meaning. Keeping your code clean out of habit will help you be able to quickly read and reason over it in the long-term.

Here is one function that can copy using the button or a click on a div content
I have used the clipboard API and delegation
SO does not allow access to the clipboard, so here is a jsfiddle that does allow it
https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vxd5e7y3/
const input = document.getElementById("cb")
const inputContainer = document.getElementById("ca")
const divContainer = document.getElementById("container")
const copyContent = (event) => {
  const tgt = event.target
  // If the copy button was clicked, copy from input field
  if (tgt?.id === "copy") {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(input.value)
  } else if (tgt.closest("div").matches(".copy-text")) {
    const text = tgt.textContent
    input.value = text
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
  }

  // Show the notification
  const notification = document.getElementById("symc")
  notification.hidden = false
  setTimeout(() => (notification.hidden = true), 1000)
}

// Listen to the click event on the buttonContainer using delegation
inputContainer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt?.id === "copy") copyContent(e);
  else if (tgt?.id === "clear") input.value = '';
})

// Add event listeners to other elements you want to copy from (here again delegation from a container element)
divContainer.addEventListener("click", copyContent)

<span id="symc" hidden>Copied</span>

<div id="ca">
  <input id="cb" />
  <button id="copy">Copy</button>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="copy-text">Text 1</div>
  <div class="copy-text">Text 2</div>
</div>


Your code works great. But want to add CLEAR button. Please provide more code for this.
<button id="clear">❌</button>
New want...
`

Copy
❌
`
And what does that button do? Clear the clipboard, the input field or both?

want to clear 
This means resetting only the input field. So adjust the clear code with the above code for the clear button.

See update and updated fiddle

Solved. Thank you very much. (^_^).

You are welcome. Please visit this help page

In the bellow code
if (tgt?.id === "copy") {     navigator.clipboard.writeText(input.value);   } else if (tgt.closest("span").matches(".copy-text")) {
and
inputContainer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {   const tgt = e.target;   if (tgt?.id === "copy") copyContent(e);   else if (tgt?.id === "clear") input.value = ''; });
Problem
I expected an identifier and instead saw '.'.
I expected and instead saw 'id'.
I expected an identifier and instead saw Expected ')' to match '(' from line 64 and instead saw 'clear'.
I expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.

Make sure the linter does not split the ? and . in ?.

Done. Thank you.
